# Conditionally update variable in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras/TF-backend. I'm trying to augment the input tensor with a randomly initialised tensor. The random tensor has probability `p` of changing and `1 - p` chance of staying the same. The random tensor will then be converted into a mask much like how [dropout](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py) is implemented in TF. All of this is wrapped inside a Keras custom layer. This is what I've got to:

```
# x is input tensor to call()
t = K.dtype(x)
renewal = K.random_uniform(shape=(1,))
renewal_prob = K.constant(self.renewal_rate, dtype=t)
keep_prob = tf.Variable(self.dropout_rate, dtype=tf.as_dtype(t), trainable=False)
print(type(random_tensor))
random_tensor = K.switch(renewal > renewal_prob,
    lambda: K.update(random_tensor,
        tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform_initializer(0., 1., dtype=tf.as_dtype(t),
                seed=seed)(noise_shape),
            validate_shape=False, trainable=False) + keep_prob),
    lambda: K.identity(random_tensor))
# 0. if [keep_prob, 1.0) and 1. if [1.0, 1.0 + keep_prob)
binary_tensor = math_ops.floor(random_tensor)
```

The print statement in the middle prints `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>` which is confusing. AFAIK it should be a variable?

In this line:

```
--> 234                                 lambda: K.identity(random_tensor))
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

My guess is any operations on a variable returns a tensor rather than another variable in Tensorflow? If this is the case, how would I conditionally update a tensor?